# Place JSON data in label in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am able to capture my data through GET method. But I wanted to display my data in a label

```
if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

      print("data: \(dataString)")
}
```

`dataString` displays

`data: {"data":{"id":1,"user_id":1,"month":9,"date":"2019-09-09 10:48:50","time_in":"09:00:00","time_out":"18:00:00","attendance":"\u25cf","reason":null,"estimated_time":null,"created_at":"2019-08-30 09:56:31","updated_at":"2019-09-09 10:49:48","deleted_at":null}}`

I wanted to get the value of "time_in" and "time_out" and display both in a label

Comment: You need to parse the JSON data, not convert it to a String. There are countless tutorials and examples on parsing JSON in Swift. Please give it a try and update your question with your attempt to parse the JSON and extract the values you need.

Comment: The data that you're getting is `JSON`. You shouldn't convert it to String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **`Codable`** to parse the JSON response.

Create the **models** like,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let data: Response
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let timeIn: String
    let timeOut: String
}
```

Now **parse** your JSON data like,

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let response = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Get the `timeIn` and `timeOut` values using `response` like,

```
let timeIn = response.data.timeIn
let timeOut = response.data.timeOut
```

You can use these `timeIn` and `timeOut` values inside your `label's` `text`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now I just missed out the part about Decodable

Comment: Why do I get an error when I change the String to Int? I have responses in Int. I kept getting 'ketNotFound' error

Comment: The JSON response you gave is String. Add the JSON response that you're getting.

Comment: I have an additional `int` in the JSON response named employee ID, i added it on the struct as `let empID: Int` but returns an error that says `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "emp_no", intValue: nil)`

Comment: There is nothing like empID or emp_no in the JSON response you added. Kindly update the JSON so I can tell you the actual reason.

Comment: I meant `"user_id":1`... its user_id. My mistake

Comment: user_id is also giving you the issue? Or is it resolved now?

Comment: Still the same issue... but only just with `int` String works as fine but the json response isnt in String so its not working